# Get ADB2C users in AD tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have two tenants - Azure AD and ADB2C.
Can we access ADB2C users in AD tenant or vice versa? I need to access AD users from ADB2C tenant somehow. Thanks!

UPD: I have app registration for API in AD tenant (let it be ar-AD) and another app registration for the client SPA in ADB2C tenant (ar-ADB2C). Is it possible to get access to the protected API endpoint to a user from the ADB2C tenant who received a token from the SPA client application? I read something about trust relationships between AD and ADB2C, but I did not find examples of setting one up and I'm not sure if this is what I need

Comment: Could you add more details like what you tried and where you stuck by editing your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we access ADB2C users in AD tenant or vice versa? I need to access AD users from ADB2C tenant somehow.

Vice versa is possible, you can **access Azure AD users from Azure AD B2C tenant**.

In the ***Azure AD tenant***, create an application and add **redirect URL** as `https://your-B2C-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-B2C-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

[image]

Now, to **configure Azure AD as an Identity Provider** *Go to Azure AD B2C tenant -> Azure AD B2C -> Identity Providers -> New OpenID Connect Provider*

Input the `ClientID` , `ClientSecret` of the Azure AD application. Make sure to pass **scope** as openid profile.

[image]

Create an Azure AD B2C user flow and select the **Identity Provider** like below:

[image]

Run the user flow:

[image]

Select **Azure AD to sign-in with AAD user account**:

[image]

The user will be added as **Member**:

[image]

You can also configure the above for Multi-Tenant Application.

According to this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/identity-providers), configuring Azure AD B2C as the Identity Provider in Azure AD is not possible.

**Reference:**

[Set up sign-in for an Azure AD organization - Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider)

Comment: Million of thanks. I will try it!

Comment: Sorry, where can I get metadata url?

Comment: Meta data URL will be like https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider

Comment: Thank you, got this metadata url. It works fine but I faced another issue: I solved authentication part but how can I solve authorization part? For ADB2C user I'm storing custom attributes assigned by graph to authorize them. How can I authorize users authenticated from AD?